# Не срабатывает запрет на кэширование.

Tags: php

```
  <?php
         header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
         header("Expires:",date("r"));
         header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s')."GMT");
         header('Cache-Control:no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate');

        ?>

        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Форма оформления заказа</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="saveorder.php" method="post">
                <p>Заказчик: <input type="text" name="name" size="50">
                <p>Email заказчика: <input type="text" name="email" 
                            size="50">
                <p>Телефон для связи: <input type="text" name="phone" 
                                size="50">
                <p>Адрес доставки: <br><textarea name="address" 
                                             cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Заказать">
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз уж топик подняли.

Однажды мне встретилось очень упрямое кеширование swf файлов, при котором часто встречаемые в интернете четыре отправленных заголовка не помогали. В итоге вспомнил про книгу в которой был вариант с шестью заголовками, который помог:

```
Header("Expires: Thu, 19 Feb 1998 13:24:18 GMT");
Header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
Header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
Header("Cache-Control: post-check=0,pre-check=0");
Header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
Header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем это делать? Браузер не может кешировать PHP-страницу без специального указания (настраивается на Web-сервере обычно).

Comment: В данном случае браузер может делать все, что ему заблагорассудится. Даже отправленные заголовки и установки он трактует, как просьбу, а не как приказ. Правда, обычно просьбу он эту удовлетворяет, но никто не гарантирует, что так будет всегда.